# String "datauristring" de JSPDF a C# para enviarlo por email como adjunto

Tags: javascript, c#, jspdf

tengo un **String** obtenido de la librería **JSPDF**

```
string = doc.output("datauristring");
```

creo un objeto y lo lleno con los datos el Email

```
var email = {};
email["toEmailAddress"] = ***;
email["emailSubject"] = "PRUEBA";
email["emailMessage"] = "PRUEBA CONTENIDO";
email["attachment"] = string;
email["attachmentName"] = "TituloAdjunto";
```

lo paso con *ajax* a un controlador. creo un **Email** y quiero mandarlo como archivo adjunto.

```
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log("respuesta: " + xhr2.responseText);
  }
};
xhr2.open('POST', '/Email/SendEmail');
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr2.send("jsonComprobante=" + JSON.stringify(email));
```

creo que al enviarlo con este formato

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

estoy haciendo lio cuando lo obtengo del lado del controlador.

en el controlador tengo esta clase creada:

```cs
        public class Email
        {
            public string toEmailAddress { get; set; }
            public string emailSubject { get; set; }
            public string emailMessage { get; set; }
            public string attachment { get; set; }
            public string attachmentName { get; set; }
        }
```

y esta es mi función para enviar el email

```cs
        public async void SendEmail(string jsonComprobante)
        {
            Email e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Email>(jsonComprobante);
            using (var message = new MailMessage())
            {
                MailAddress from = ***;

                message.From = from;
                message.To.Add(e.toEmailAddress);
                message.Subject = e.emailSubject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = e.emailMessage;

                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(e.attachment);
                MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                Attachment data = new Attachment(strm, "fileName.pdf");

                message.Attachments.Add(data);

                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(***, ***))
                {
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(***,***);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = bool.Parse(***);
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

todo funciona bien, pero el PDF que me llega no lo abre. claramente esta mal creado.

creo que mi problema esta en como paso el objeto de javascript a c#. alguno me puede dar una mano? GRACIAS!

Comment: Y si intentas meterlo a un blob y del blob mandarlo como archivo en un input file?

Comment: encontre que en base64 tenemos "+,-,=" etc y tengo que pasarlo a UTF8 para que pase bien... voy a probar con eso...

Comment: le estás dando mucha vuelta, intenta lo mencionado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo Solucioné!!

en la función de JavaScript:

```
email["attachment"] = atob(string.replace("data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,", ""));
```

así paso el PDF y en el controlador en la función del Email lo recibo así:

```cs
                Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(e.attachment);
                byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
                //string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);


                MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(isoBytes);
                Attachment data = new Attachment(strm, e.attachmentName, "application/pdf");
                ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
                data.ContentId = "fileName.pdf";
                data.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

                message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

el problema, como suponía, estaba en la forma que pasaba la información. seguro hay otras formas de resolverlo.

no se que es un BLOB y no se como pasarlo en ajax como input file. :S

GRACIAS POR SU TIEMPO!! ;)

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada y de ese modo los demás nos enteramos que con esto diste solución a tu problema

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta en 23 horas :S

Comment: Si hay que ser un poco pacientes, pero hey lo importante es tu solución y tu aporte logrado por ti mismo +1

Comment: si! gracias! ;)